# can't connect to Sql Sever Management Express 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I installed `Sql Sever Management Express 2012` , but when i try to connect in Sql management studio environment , i have this error .

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

The system cannot find the file specified

BUTTONS:
OK

and in during installation i dont have option for select cluster !!

this is my SQL Server Configuration Manager , my sql server service is empty ...

And when get Remove a Failover Cluster Node , this error happened .

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2lrvat.jpg

when i enter SQLEXPRESS , i have error

```
Cannot connect to SQLEXPRESS. ------------------------------ 
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewing your linked images, is clear that you haven't installed or installed unsuccesfully,

```
 Sql Server  Express 2012
```

In your Configuration Server Manager there is no instancse of `SQL Server` so it is normal not been able to connect.

Q: Sine there is no instance,when you Launch Management Studio what instance name do you select when you try to connect???

You should properly install [SQL Server Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

**EDIT :**

First Check if you have any version of SQL Server or SQL Server Express installed on your machine...(this can be done by looking through installed programs from control panel)

In order to Install and configure SQL Express 2008 follow  [this steps](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/install-and-configure-sql-server-2008-express)

Take in mind that you have to use SQL Management Studio 2008 later on (if you have 2008 server)

Hope it helps...

Comment: Answer : i don't have any idea for instance name to connect the server . i question this problem in other site and on of the people say enter SQLEXPRESS(default instanse name for Sql  ) to connect server . http://serverfault.com/questions/601317/cant-connect-to-sql-sever-management-express-2012

Comment: i'm study in college and i have a simple project for my university that need to Sql , and i need sql management studio . what version you prefer for me .. i'm from iran anad i can't download from microsoft (You put Sql link from microsoft website ) .. what is you oponion about version ? i installed sql express 2008 few days ago but i still Astounding about this problem !!!

Comment: @Rare-Man, it seems that SQL 2008 server is not properly installed..Install it correct..see my edit